# Need to deploy from archiva to weblogic using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, weblogic12c, archiva

We use Jenkins for building maven projects, analysing code and pushing our builds to archiva(via mvn deploy).

I need to have a deploy item that grabs a war from archiva and pushes it to weblogic.

Checking if this can be easily done without scripting something.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

- you can use [WebLogic Deployer Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/WebLogic+Deployer+Plugin) to deploy your files.
- `**/*.war` only selects the war file from your archiva.

Comment: Thanks, I have that piece working now using a network path to archiva location, was wondering if I could get over http from apache archiva to workspace and then push to weblogic. Thanks